# What are the latest Innovative Audio Technologies

Tags: audio

Just to get up to date,

Do you have any links to websites/blogs, magazine or shops (this could be one specific shop's category) dedicated exclusively to innovative audio technologies (hardware, web, software, data network)?

By innovative I mean technologies that deeply change the industry and consumer approach to products.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sweetwater.com?

Comment: This one is more of a normal online music shop :( thx anyway